# Can we use incidence to describe occurance?

Tags: differences

I have looked up examples for the use of incidence. While many give examples relating to rate/frequency, none gave me examples realtimg to occurance.

For example, i was told that using 'the last incidence of violence occured in february 'was wrong. Incident would have been a better use there.

incidence
ˈɪnsɪd(ə)ns/Submit
noun
1.
the occurrence, rate, or frequency of a disease, crime, or other undesirable thing.
"an increased incidence of cancer"
synonyms:   occurrence, prevalence, commonness; More

Comment: There’s no such word as *occurance*.

Comment: Kians, it's not untrue that "incidence" can be synonymous with "inceident" and to you, what's the difference?

It's great that you looked up examples and a greater shame that you didn't cite a result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word [instance](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/instance) one definition of which is

> A particular example or occurrence of something

Whereas [incidence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/incidence) is more usually defined in this context as

> The rate at which something happens

However the Cambridge online dictionary gives the definition of *incidence* as

> **An event** or the rate at which something happens

With the following as an example

> There have been quite a few incidences of bullying in the school this year

Which is the sense in which you were using it. I don't know who told you it was wrong but the Cambridge dictionary disagrees with them.